Open a file from within the Eclipse Console window
Is there any way I can open a file in it's default application from within the Eclipse Console window? More specifically, an application I have run has logged a filepath to system out. I was hoping to be able to select and right click and be able to open the file.

The plugin AnyEdit Tools adds Open file under cursor to the right-click menu in text editors and also in the Console view.
In most cases, this command works even without having to select the file first.
